# Proof Stirling Numbers of First Kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

The following three equations of the Stirling numbers (kind 1) should be proved:

1) $S_{n+1,k} = s_{n,k-1} + ns_{n,k}$

2) $s_{n,1} = (n-1)!$

3) $s_{n,n-1} = \binom{n}{2}$

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the definition of stirling numbers that you are working with?

Comment: We are using the stirling numbers of first kind. $s_{n}$ is the amount of permutations $\pi \in S_{n}$, which has exact k cycles. $\pi = (a_{1,1}...a_{1,k_{1}}) \circ ... \circ (a_{m,1} ... a_{m,k_{m}})$

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the first and third.

Let $\pi$ be an arbitrary permutation of the natural numbers from $1$ through $n+1$ that has $k$ cycles.  Consider where $n+1$ is in that permutation.  There are two possibilities:

- $n+1$ is fixed by $\pi$; i.e. it is alone in its own cycle.  The remaining $n$ elements form $k-1$ cycles, so there are $s_{n,k-1}$ of these.
- $n+1$ is not fixed by $\pi$.  These can be "built" by taking one of the $s_{n,k}$ permutations of the natural numbers from $1$ through $n$ and "inserting" $n+1$ after any of the $n$ elements in its cycle.  Therefore, there are $ns_{n,k}$ permutations where $n+1$ is not fixed.

Since those two cases are exhaustive, we conclude the recurrence relation $s_{n+1,k}=s_{n,k-1}+ns_{n,k}$.

---

$s_{n,n-1}$ represents the number of permutations of $n$ elements into $n-1$ cycles.  This clearly can only be achieved by a single transposition.  We designate these by choosing the two elements that are to be swapped, so this can be done in $n\choose 2$ ways.